# Gulp Watch produces memory leak

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I am having an issue where after several restarts triggered by gulp watch, I get a warning that states I may have a memory leak. I assume it's because I am starting a new instance of gulp watch with every restart, triggering a new server and another new watch, over and over. I am not sure that's the case and not sure how to fix it if it is.

Here is my gulpfile.js.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

gulp.task('dev', (() => {
  gulp.start('test');
  gulp.start('lint');
  gulp.start('server');
  gulp.start('watch');
  return gutil.log('Gulp is running!');
}));

gulp.task('server', (cb) => {
  exec('npm start', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    gutil.log(stdout);
    gutil.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
});

gulp.task('test', (cb) => {
  exec('npm test', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    gutil.log(stdout);
    gutil.log(stderr);
    cb(err);
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {
  gulp.watch(['./app.js', './views/*', './routes/*'], ['dev']);
});

gulp.task('lint', () => {
  return gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**'])
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format());
});
```

And my error is:

```
(node:808) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 change listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Comment: I added the warning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `gulp.watch` calls the task `dev` which in turn creates another `gulp.watch`. My money is on that.

Comment: That's what I think too, is there a way to avoid it? Does gulp have a way of killing tasks? Because right now I think every time watch runs dev, I am getting a new npm start without stopping the old one also.

Comment: instead of calling `dev` call `lint`.

Answer (score 1):

As another user noted, you're calling `gulp dev` in `gulp watch` basically creating an inifinity loop, which would cause that.

To add, I would encourage using a default task:

```
gulp.task('default', ['dev', 'test', 'lint', 'watch', 'server']);
```